# Sin acceso a controles en asp.net con el atributo runat="server"

Tags: asp.net-web-api, .netframework

En una *singlepage* de ASP.Net con NetFramework 4.7.2 formado por los archivos index.aspx y a su "código asociado" Index.aspx.cs. Al declarar un control con su ID y el atributo  runat="Server" no lo puedo llamar desde parte código porque dice que no existe en el mismo "contexto". Previamente a encontrarme con este problema el código funcionaba, cuando ejecutaba en un servidor iis tradicional con configuraciones por defecto, pero al agregar los archivos, en un proyecto asp.net con Visual Studio 2022 en blanco me dan dicho error.

**Codigo de index.aspx:**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="index.aspx.cs" Inherits="MyNamespace.Index" %>
```

....

```
<div id="mensaje"  runat="server" class="alert alert-success" role="alert" style="display: none">
        <asp:Label ID="mensajito" runat="server"/>
    </div>
```

Codigo de index.aspx.cs

```
namespace MyNamespace
{

    public partial class Index : Page
    {
        public int cantidad;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var message = Request.QueryString["mensaje"];
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
            {
                mensaje.Attributes["style"] = "display:block;";               
                mensajito.Text = message;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**El mensaje de error es:**

```
El nombre 'mensaje' no existe en el contexto actual
El nombre 'mensajito' no existe en el contexto actual
```

Como dije anteriormente, el error se presenta cuando en un proyecto vacío de asp.net agrego el código anterior, pero si lo ejecuto en un root de iis con configuración tradicional, lo carga sin errores.